¿Cómo puedo desactivar el optimizador de consultas de postgresql?
Necesito hacer unas pruebas de una consulta y la segunda vez que corro la misma consulta el tiempo de respuesta es superior, pero quisiera desactivar esa optimización. ¿ Cómo puedo hacer ?

Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

No hay forma de ejecutar una consulta sin un plan, y el plan te lo da justamente el optimizador. Posiblemente puedeas modificar algun comportamiento del mismo, pero deshabilitarlo completamente, no es posible.

Gracias, entonces la única manera es reiniciando el ordenador.

ni si quiera reiniciando el ordenador, el siempre esta ahi, mira la respuesta que te di para jugar con algunas opciones y cambar su comportamiento

Primero que todo el optimizador de consultas es muy bueno(puede no tener el mejor plan en ocasiones) si tienes estadisticas actualizadas de las tablas involucradas en la consulta. Ahora para desactivar/activar algunas estrategias puedes jugar(activandolas y desactivandolas) con las variables de configuracion del plannificador de consultas
por ejemplo:
set enable_seqscan = off; --desactiva el escaneo secuancial 
--ejecuta tu consulta 
set enable_seqscan to default; --dejalo por deefecto (on)


